# JS Cose doesn't run

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, attributes, getelementbyid

I'd like to know why my code doesn't work.I'm just trying to change the height attribute from '1000' to '2'
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canv" width="1000" height="1000" onclick="click()" onmousemove=""></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
function click(){
    var l = document.getElementById("canv");
    l.height = "2";

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've called your handler `click`. `onxyz`-style attribute handlers are executed in an environment that has the element itself mixed into scope, so `click` in your handler refers to the `click` on the canvas itself, not the global function. So your global function isn't being called.

If you use a different name, you don't have the conflict, and the global function is called:

```js
function clickCanvas(){
    console.log("Got here");
    var l = document.getElementById("canv");
    l.height = "2";
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="1000" height="1000" onclick="clickCanvas()" onmousemove=""></canvas>
```

---

I strongly recommend not using `onxyz`-attribute-style handlers, though, not least because they rely on global functions, and globals are a Bad Thing™. Instead, hook up your handler with modern event handling, which in addition to playing nicely with others wouldn't have had the name conflict problem you had. It also lets you use `this` in the handler to refer to the element on which you hooked the event:

```js
document.getElementById("canv").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Got here");
    this.height = "2";
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ive been doing js for many many years, and never once have I picked up that you cant name the function the same as the event when using `onxyz` markup. I had to double check this with jsfiddle to quite believe it!

Comment: @Jamiec: Trust your uncle T.J... ;-) *(Trust...but verify.)*